# Reading from a textfile and writing to another textfile

Tags: c#

I have Data in Notepad that looks like this
and I'm writing it to an output file

```
01 some Data
02 some Data
02 some data
03 some data(End of client 1)
01 some data 
02 some data
02 some data
02 some data
03 some data(End of client 2)
```

I want to count how many times the value `02` appears and display it after the end of each client.

I'm using this piece of code to count

```
int count = File.ReadLines(@"C:\Exercises\gamenam.dat").Count(
               line => line.StartsWith("02")
               );
```

I want to know how do you display it after the end of each client ie after 03?

Comment: Try to use a loop to iterate over the result of `ReadLines` yourself rather than one of the LINQ functions in this case.

Comment: Why not a simpler approach? Loop through the lines, have a counter increase if line starts with 02, at a defined number of iterations, reset the counter and print the result.

Answer (score 0):

This might be easier to do with a loop and regex:

```
int count = 0;
foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(@"C:\Exercises\gamenam.dat"))
{
    if (line.StartsWith("02"))
        count++;

    Match clientMatch = Regex.Match(line, @"(?<=\(End of client )\d+(?=\))");
    if (clientMatch.Success)
    {
        // Replace line below with write to output file
        Console.WriteLine("Client {0} has {1} occurrences of \"02\".", 
                          clientMatch.Value, count);
        count = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Douglas But (End of client) doesn't exist in the text file I just put it there so youll can understand that it represents 1 client,My question is how to read the last value of the client and after that show howmany times 02 appears

Comment: What is your email address ill show you what it suppose to look like

Comment: @user3321109: How do you identify that a client has ended? Could you post a redacted example to your question?

Comment: Each client starts with 01 and ends with 05 so after the 05 you need to show howmany times did 05 occur